# How to sort a string field containing numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table 'orders'. it likes below :

| table_number (string) | people_number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2B | 4 |
| A1 | 3 |
| B2 | 4 |
| C1 | 3 |
| 1A | 4 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| CA7 | 4 |
| TB89 | 4 |
| T85 | 4 |
| CA78 | 4 |
| B239 | 4 |
| E9 | 4 |

Field `table_number` is A random combination of all numbers and letters. So it's a string column, I want to order table_number like the result below :

| table_number (string) | people_number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1A | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2B | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 10 | 3 |
| A1 | 3 |
| B2 | 4 |
| B239 | 4 |
| C1 | 3 |
| CA7 | 4 |
| CA78 | 4 |
| E9 | 4 |
| T85 | 4 |
| TB89 | 4 |

Comment: Why do you have mixed numbers and letters? Presumably the letters carry specific meaning so should be a separate column, this violates basic first normal form.

Comment: You need to separate the numbers and letter first. Once you do that sorting is easy.

Comment: @Stu, juste thinking about that, the application is a PDA order system in restaurant, the server use it to open the new table. they will give a table number like 1, 2, 3 or may be A1, T2 whatever if they want to.

Comment: @孙悟空 That's where a good application design understands the requirements and provisions the schema correctly, it seems this table "number" is more than just an identifer and carries additional meaning (area or location?), given your requirement to sort rows based on two different parts of the composite value.

Comment: You are showing values consisting of digits + letters and letters + digits. Is this the only two formats that exist in the table? Or can there be digits only, letters only, digits-letters-digits, letters-digits-letters, ...?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, A random combination of all numbers and letters

Comment: With completely random combinations like 'A12B3' and '1A23BC', sorting becomes quite a task. You want to separate letters from digits and sort one by one, e.g. '1A23BC' gets sorted by 1, 'A', 23, 'BC'. This is an iterative process with a variable number of sub sortkeys. One solution may be to pad every combination with the maximum number of allowed characters to get a sortkey. E.g. if the maximum string length is six, then '1A23BC' could become '000001A_____000023BC____'. If you need this often, then add this sortkey as a column to your table and fill it at insert time with a trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *cast* as *signed* while sorting like

```
 ORDER BY 1-SIGN(CAST(table_number AS SIGNED)), -- check whether castable which will have the precedence after applying 1-SIGN(...)
          CAST(table_number AS SIGNED)          -- sort each group among themselves
```

or shorter version might be

```
 ORDER BY 1-SIGN(table_number+0), table_number+0
```

**Edit**(*considering the new edited data set*): You can use the following sorting style **:**

```
 ORDER BY  1-SIGN(table_number+0), -- check whether castable(eg.the values starting with an integer) which will have the precedence after applying 1-SIGN(...)
           table_number+0,  -- the integer part extracted from the whole values those start with a non-integer 
           table_number     -- the values starting with a non-integer
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d28ca181f2d484bdf23439d37317706)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it isn't correct your answer... when we have 1, 2, 3, 1B,2C,CA7,
TB89,
T85,
CA78,
B239,
E9,
B86,
tt, B1, T1, TA1, A1 etc .., with this sorting, it doesn't wok

Comment: Hi @孙悟空 , you're welcome. Can you add this data set, and how should they be sorted to the question as well?

Comment: Ok question is updated

Comment: @孙悟空 OK, the answer is updated as well

Comment: Thank you, If I have more than 5 000 000 lines, will it become slow ?

Comment: You're welcome @孙悟空 surely it will be slow since sorting is such a costly operation, especially for larger data set.